# JQUERY Looping an Array

Tags: jquery

I have an AJAX array returning to JQUERY as follows:

[image]

I can see the array if I do this:

```
 alert(data);
```

I then run the array through JSON decode as follows:

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now I need to be able to look through the array and access the elements. I've tried a few ways but I can't see to hook into the elements - eg: jquery error as page doesn't show.

This is one of the ways I've tried:

```
obj.each(function(key, value) {
    alert(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Missing something - any help would be really appreciated.

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330099/jquery-question-about-looping-through-an-array

Hope that helps.

Comment: Probably the data isn't legal JSON so `JSON.parse()` doesn't handle it.  What is in obj after you call `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: yes your right the data wasn't JSON so I've dropped the parse()... also added }); after .each() and the page now shows... but still can't get access the array contents... hummmmmm

Comment: that looks like php returned data.  do you have the option of encoding it as json from the server using `json_encode($data)`?  If that is not the case, then try surrounding that `obj.each` loop for a regular `for` loop that iterates through that array

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = '[{ "metatype": "descriptions", "pagename": "index", "metacontent": "testing1" }, { "metatype": "keywords", "pagename": "index", "metacontent": "testing2" }, { "metatype": "title", "pagename": "index", "metacontent": "testing3"}]';
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(obj, function (i, entity) {
                $('#result').append('<div>' + i + ": " + entity.metatype + ' ' + entity.pagename + ' ' + entity.metacontent + '</div>');
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    enter code here
```